# Div desalinhada bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap

Tenho a seguinte DIV

```
<section id="section-base">
    <div class="container">
        <h3>cases</h3>
        <div class="row">
            <?php foreach($cases as $valor){ ?>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url("inicial/wide_image/".$valor->imagem.'/250/200'); ?>" style="padding:5px;" class='img-responsive'>
                    <div class="row text-justify">
                        <h4><?php echo $valor->titulo; ?></h4>
                        <p><?php echo $valor->descricao; ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>          
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Porém na hora de imprimir as divs, elas ficam desalinhadas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu posso ajustar? Gostaria de colocar uma borda também em cada uma das divs.

Comment: Elas são `display:inline-block` ?

Comment: Se for coloque um `vertical-align: top` nelas e já era.

Comment: se quiser deixar todas com o mesmo tamanho e/ou alinhadas perfeitamente, sugiro dar uma olhada na css-tricks na parte de `display:flex` (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Em resposta a borda, pegue a classe dos elementos, e adicione um `border: [none~9999+ px] [solid,dashed,inset,outset, etc..] [color (hex,rgb,rgba,etc...)]`

Comment: @Inkeliz, ele pode não estar utilizando o bootstrap, sendo assim não é possível cogitar uma hipótese de duplicata. :/

Comment: @MuriloGambôa Pelo `col-md-3` e `row` acho que é Bootstrap e o mesmo problema de alinhamento. Essa sua solução acho que também dava uma resposta para essa e para a outra pergunta também.

Comment: Coloca a mesma altura em todas.

Comment: @AntonioAlexandre, se ele setar uma altura, pode ocorrer de uma div precisar de mais altura, setar isso como algo fixo é ruim :/

Comment: Ao que parece, o PHP está gerando mais de 4 divs com `col-md-3` (pela imagem parecem ser 6), isso que está deixando desalinhado, já que o limite é 12(4 colunas de tamanho 3), duas das colunas são jogadas pra baixo.

Comment: Sendo problema de layout seria melhor tu postar o código HTML gerado usando a ferramenta de desenvolvedor do navegador..

Comment: Exatamente, @pliavi, as colunas do bootstrap possuem float definido no CSS e como as divs definidas no PHP possuem alturas distintas, as duas últimas ficarão desalinhadas. Acredito que o ideal seria definir uma div com a classe row `div classe="row"` a cada 4 elementos impressos (ou controlar a altura dos elementos deixando-a fixa, o que é um pouco complicado quando se trata de conteúdo dinâmico).

Comment: @MuriloGambôa, você está certo. Pôr altura não é a melhor solução. Melhor seria ele englobar em divs de linha, mas daí precisa limitar a quantidade de blocos por linha pras divs não treparem umas em cima das outras como está ocorrendo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento isso é bootstrap

Comment: http://www.mkweb.inf.br/site/cases

Comment: Sim são 4 colunas.

Comment: @AndréBaill corrigi a resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/180194/3635

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52543/discussion-on-question-by-andre-baill-div-desalinhada-bootstrap)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ele não está quebrando é você quem está usando `col-md-` errado, se fizer isso (seu código):

```
<div class="col-md-3">...</div>
<div class="col-md-3">...</div>
<div class="col-md-3">...</div>
<div class="col-md-3">...</div>
<div class="col-md-3">...</div>
<div class="col-md-3">...</div>
<div class="col-md-3">...</div>
<div class="col-md-3">...</div>
```

É lógico que ele vai exceder a largura e quebra, fora que `col-md` usa `float`, ou seja ele vai tentar se ajeitar abaixo do elemento de menor altura.

É como eu expliquei aqui:

- [Evitar quebra de linha (encavalando) em col-md bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/129074/3635)

A sua quantidade de grids esta errada, mesmo que use o `.row`, o `.col-*-3` deve ter apenas 4 divs em um mesmo `.row`, ou seja para cada `.row` você deve só ter 4 `.col-md-3` por exemplo.

Pra saber se a quantidade sempre some os valores do final do `col-`, se termina em `-3` então é `3`, então deve ter `4` divs pois o total sempre deve ser 12, ou seja:

- Se for usar apenas `.col-*-3` então será 4, pois 3+3+3+3 = 12
- Se for usar apenas `.col-*-4` então será 3, pois 4+4+4 = 12
- Se usar `.col-*-6` será 6+6=12
- Também pode fazer 6+3+3=12 por exemplo.

Para resolver com loop, `foreach`, `for` ou `while`, pode fazer assim usando `$i % 4`:

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>cases</h3>

    <?php $i = 0; ?>
    <?php foreach($cases as $valor){ ?>
    <?php
    $needarow = !($i % 4);
    $i++;//Deve vir depois
    ?>
    <?php if ($needarow) { ?>
    <?php if ($i > 1) { ?>

    </div> <!-- //fecha .row -->

    <?php } ?>

    <div class="row">

    <?php }?>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url("inicial/wide_image/".$valor->imagem.'/250/200'); ?>" style="padding:5px;" class='img-responsive'>
            <div class="row text-justify">
                <h4><?php echo $valor->titulo; ?></h4>
                <p><?php echo $valor->descricao; ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php } ?>

    </div> <!-- //ultimo .row -->

</div> <!-- //fecha .container -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Esse problema de divs trepando em cima da outra costuma ser recorrente, não apenas com Bootstrap.

Entenda o problema:
Normalmente se tem divs de várias alturas diferentes sendo colocadas uma ao lado da outra. Acontece que na hora que o navegador renderiza a mesma ela é gerada à direita do último bloco e depois realocada para esquerda com o float left, ficando presa no bloco com a altura um pouco maior.

Segue abaixo um exemplo de código demonstrando o problema. Repare que os blocos EEE, FFF, GGG e HHH vão se alocando ao lados uns dos outros mas ficando presos do lado direito por causa da altura do bloco BBB.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Colunas</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <style>
  section { width:800px; margin:auto; border:1px solid #ccc; }
  div { width:180px; background-color:#f1d; margin:5px; padding:5px;  float:left; }
 </style>

</head>
<body>

 <section>
 
  <div>AAA AAA AAA<br> AAA AAA<br>  AAA</div>
  <div>BBB BBB BBB <br> BBB <br> BBB BBB  <br> BBB <br> BBB BBB  <br> BBB BBB </div>
  <div>CCC CCC<br> CCC CCC CCC<br> CCC</div>
  <div>DDD DDD<br> DDD<br> DDD DDD</div>
  
  <div>EEE</div>
  <div>FFF</div>
  <div>GGG</div>
  <div>HHH</div>
  
  <br clear="both">
 
 </section>


</body>
</html>
```

Tenho duas sugestões para resolver o problema:

1ª opção) Definir altura fixa para os blocos. Isso não é muito bom caso você tenha alturas variando muito e sempre. Se a altura não for variar demais e não correr o risco de ter o conteúdo de uma delas excedendo essa altura, essa é uma boa opção. Segue exemplo abaixo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Colunas</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <style>
  section { width:800px; margin:auto; border:1px solid #ccc; }
  div { width:180px; height:150px; background-color:#f1d; margin:5px; padding:5px;  float:left; }
 </style>

</head>
<body>

 <section>
 
  <div>AAA AAA AAA<br> AAA AAA<br>  AAA</div>
  <div>BBB BBB BBB <br> BBB <br> BBB BBB  <br> BBB <br> BBB BBB  <br> BBB BBB </div>
  <div>CCC CCC<br> CCC CCC CCC<br> CCC</div>
  <div>DDD DDD<br> DDD<br> DDD DDD</div>
  
  <div>EEE</div>
  <div>FFF</div>
  <div>GGG</div>
  <div>HHH</div>
  
  <br clear="both">
 
 </section>


</body>
</html>
```

2ª opção) Pôr os blocos em divs "linha". Se a quantidade dos seus ítens por linha for sempre o mesmo, independente da resolução, essa é a melhor solução. Segue um exemplo usando linhas abaixo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Colunas</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <style>
  section { width:800px; margin:auto; border:1px solid #ccc; }
  div { width:180px; background-color:#f1d; margin:5px; padding:5px;  float:left; }
  .linha { width:800px; background-color:#ffc; padding:0; margin:0; float:left; }
 </style>

</head>
<body>

 <section>
 
  <div class="linha">
   <div>AAA AAA AAA<br> AAA AAA<br>  AAA</div>
   <div>BBB BBB BBB <br> BBB <br> BBB BBB  <br> BBB <br> BBB BBB  <br> BBB BBB </div>
   <div>CCC CCC<br> CCC CCC CCC<br> CCC</div>
   <div>DDD DDD<br> DDD<br> DDD DDD</div>
  </div>

  <div class="linha">
   <div>EEE</div>
   <div>FFF</div>
   <div>GGG</div>
   <div>HHH</div>
  </div>

  <br clear="both">
 </section>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Amigo, não é esse o problema, a questão é que nos GRIDs de CSS a soma deve ser sempre 12 (numero que vai após `col-md-`), por exemplo se tiver `div class=col-md-4`+`div class=col-md-3`+`div class=col-md-3`+`div class=col-md-2` ele vai funcionar, porque o total foi 12 (4+3+3+2=12), as se fizer `div class=col-md-4`+`div class=col-md-3`+`div class=col-md-3`+`div class=col-md-3`, o total será 13 (4+3+3+3=13) e irá quebrar, como expliquei em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/129074/3635