# Itens do menu desalinhados CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, bootstrap-3

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web e desenvolvi um menu com alguns icons mas ao diminuir a largura da pagina os icons se desalinham  e esse é meu menu

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mas ao diminuir a largura da pagina acontece isso com os componentes do menu.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
   <div class="header-fixed">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-left">
            <a class="fa fa-home"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-center">
            <a class="fa fa-user"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-right">
             <a class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div> 

      .header-fixed {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
    background-color: #6495ED;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  height: 37px;
  font-size: 20pt;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como eu já expliquei em:

- [Div desalinhada bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/180194/3635)
- [Lado a lado no Bootstrap, tá pulando linha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/180205/3635)
- [Problema ao Alinhar conteúdo com CSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/262077/3635)

A soma dos cols tem que ser **sempre igual** a 12, no entanto sua cols-xs são:

- col-xs-12+col-xs-12+col-xs-12 (12+12+12) = 36 (**errado**)
- col-sm-4+col-sm-4+col-sm-4 (4+4+4) = 12 (**correto**)

O certo deveria ser:

- col-xs-4+col-xs-4+col-xs-4 (4+4+4) = 12

Exemplo:

```
<div class="header-fixed">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 text-left">
                <a class="fa fa-home"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 text-center">
                <a class="fa fa-user"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 text-right">
                 <a class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Se bem que no caso nem precisa do `sm`, já que o `xs` é idêntico, então mude para:

```
<div class="header-fixed">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 text-left">
                <a class="fa fa-home"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                <a class="fa fa-user"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">
                 <a class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```