# Problema ao Alinhar conteúdo com CSS

Tags: php, html, css

Você pode ver direto no site nesse link: http://www.cinepophd.ml/index.php?browse/playseries/1/1

Alguém sabe me dizer porque a grade de episódios está ficando assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**O codigo que estou usando é:**

```
 <div class="row">

    <?php

    $counter    =   0;

    $episodes   =   $this->crud_model->get_episodes_of_season($season_id);

    foreach ($episodes as $row2):

    ?>

    <div class="col-md-3">

    <a href="#" onclick="jwplayer().playlistItem(<?php echo $counter++;?>)">

    <img src="<?php echo $this->crud_model->get_thumb_url('episode' , $row2['episode_id']);?>" 

    style="height: 150px; margin-top:10px;" /></a>

    <br>

    <h5><?php echo $row2['title'];?></h5>

    </div>

    <?php endforeach;?>

    </div>
```

E no início da pagina tem um css com esse codigo:

```css
 .movie_thumb{}
 
.btn_opaque{font-size:20px; border: 1px solid #939393;text-decoration: none;margin: 10px;background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.74); color: #fff;}
 
.btn_opaque:hover{border: 1px solid #939393;text-decoration: none;background-color: rgba(57, 57, 57, 0.74);color:#fff;}
 
.video_cover {position: relative;padding-bottom: 30px;}
 
.video_cover:after {
 content : "";
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background-image: url(<?php echo $this->crud_model->get_poster_url('series' , $row['series_id']);?>); 
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 opacity : 0.2;
 z-index: -1;
 background-size:cover;
 }
 
.select_black{background-color: #000;height: 45px;padding: 12px;font-weight: bold;color: #fff;}
 
.profile_manage{font-size: 25px;border: 1px solid #ccc;padding: 5px 30px;text-decoration: none;}
 
.profile_manage:hover{font-size: 25px;border: 1px solid #fff;padding: 5px 30px;text-decoration: none;color:#fff;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Como eu respondi em:

- [**Lado a lado no Bootstrap, tá pulando linha**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/180205/3635)
- [**Evitar quebra de linha (encavalando) em col-md bootstrap**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/129074/3635)

A soma de todos cols sempre deve ser `12`, por exemplo:

- Se tiver 4 divs com a classe `.col-*-3` então a soma será 12 (3+3+3+3 = 12)
- Se tiver 3 divs com a classe `.col-*-4` então a soma será 12 (4+4+4 = 12)
- Também pode fazer `.col-*-6`+`.col-*-3`+`.col-*-3` por exemplo (6+3+3=12)

Em seu código, existem 5 colunas, ou seja `5 (colunas)` * `3 (col-md-3)` = 15, passando os 12 de limite.

A solução ou é limitar para 4 colunas (4*3=12) ou usar `col-md-2` (2*5=10), daria até para colocar 6 colunas, ou compensar o espaço com `col-*-offset-*`

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma nova `.row` a cada 4 colunas. Você pode utilizar a variável `$counter = 0;` dentro do laço para criar uma nova `.row`.

Para isso, adicione este `if` no final do laço `foreach`:

```
if($counter%4 == 0){
   echo '</div><div class="row dvd">';
}
```

O `if` verifica se o `$counter` é múltiplo de 4 e insere uma nova `.row` fechando a anterior.

O código ficaria assim:

```
<div class="row">
   <?php
   $counter    =   0;
   $episodes   =   $this->crud_model->get_episodes_of_season($season_id);

   foreach ($episodes as $row2):
   ?>

   <div class="col-md-3">
      <a href="#" onclick="jwplayer().playlistItem(<?php echo $counter++;?>)">
         <img src="<?php echo $this->crud_model->get_thumb_url('episode' , $row2['episode_id']);?>" style="height: 150px; margin-top:10px;" />
      </a>
      <br>
      <h5><?php echo $row2['title'];?></h5>
   </div>
   <?php
      if($counter%4 == 0){
        echo '</div><div class="row">';
      }
   endforeach;
   ?>
</div>
```