# Grids Boostrap Ajuda

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout-responsivo, grid

Boa noite pessoal estou com um problema estou aprendendo fazer um site, estou com algumas duvidas referentes a sistema de grids dei uma pesquisada não entendi muito bem por isso vim ate aqui no fórum , esta acontecendo quando dou zoom na pagina as coisas saem do lugar

Estou na aba quem somos do menu mas acontece em todas paginas 
só o topo o menu e o fundo , alguém pode me ajudar ou me indicar algo que eu possa melhorar ou estudar.
[image: aba quem somos]

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


#topo {
 background:url(../imagens/topo2etrelas2.png);
 border-left:1px solid #000;
 border-right:1px solid #000; 
 position:inherit;
 width:1024px;
 height:190px;
 margin:auto;
 

}


#fundoinicial {
 background: #FFF;
 width: 1024px;
 height: 500px;
 margin: auto;
 border-right: 1px solid #000;
 border-left: 1px solid #000;
 
}

h3 {
 font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
 font-size:25px;
 position:absolute;
 top:271px;
 left:618px;
 text-shadow: #60365E 0px 0px 5px;
 
}


p1 {
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:15px;
 position:absolute;
 width:1000px;
 top:350px;
 left:179px;
 text-align:center; 
}




hr {
      border: 0;
      height: 1px;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
   width:300px;
   position:absolute;
   top: 300px;
   left: 512px;
   margin:auto;
 
   
    }

#baixo {
 border: 0;
      height: 1px;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
   width:1050px;
   position:absolute;
   top: 250px;
   left: -25px;
   margin:auto;
}

#menufundo {
 background:#60365e;
 border:1px solid #000;
 position:relative;
 width:1024px;
 height:28px;
 margin:auto;
 
 
 
 
}


#ul li a{
 font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive;
 font-style:normal;
 list-style-type:none;
 display: inline;
 font-size:19px;
 line-height:0px;
 padding:10px;
    margin:4px 0 0 52px;
 color:#FFF;
 text-decoration:none;
 float:left;
 
 
}

#ul li a:hover{
 text-shadow:0px 0px 0px black,
    0px 0px 0px black,
    0px 0px 0px black,
    0px 0px 0px black; 
 font-size:19px;
    color:black;
}


.rodape {
 background: url(../imagens/rodape.png);
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 width: 1056px;
 height: 99px;
 left: 132px;
 top: 704px;
 
}
 


h1 a{
 font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
 font-size: 19px;
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
 position: absolute;
 left: 176px;
 top: 714px;
 
}

p a{
 font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
 position: absolute;
 left: 175px;
 top: 743px;
}

.facebook{
 width: 32px;
 right: 32px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 25px;
 left: 515px;
 opacity: 0.5;
 filter: alpha(opacity=50);
 
}

.facebook:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

.trabalhe {
 font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
 font-size: 19px;
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
 position: absolute;
 left: 986px;
 top: 729px;
 width: 159px;

}

.email {
 font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 20px;
 left: 987px;
 top: 736px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Alfatec</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="imagens/ico.png" type="imagem/x-png" />
<link href="css/resetquemsomos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/estiloquemsomos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript"  src="jquery/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.min.js" ></script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
 background-image: url(imagens/projeto/imagens/fundo.jpg);
}
</style>
</head>


<body>


<div id="topo"></div><!--div final topo-->
<div id="menufundo">

<nav id="ul">    
          <ul>            
           <li><a href="index.html" title="Página Inicial">Página Inicial</a></li> 
           <li><a href="quem_somos.html" title="Quem Somos">Quem Somos</a></li>
           <li><a href="cobertura.html" title="Áreas de Cobertura">Áreas de Cobertura</a></li> 
           <li><a href="servicos.html" title="Serviços">Serviços</a></li>
           <li><a href="fale_conosco.html" title="Fale Conosco">Fale Conosco</a></li>
       </ul>
</nav>
</div>

         
<div id ="fundoinicial">

<h3>Alfatec</h3>
<hr />

<p1> A empresa (nome da empresa) foi fundada no ano de (ano da fundação, por exemplo, 1998) na cidade (nome da cidade) pelo Senhor (nome do fundador) e sua principal missão é oferecer soluções para empresas de e-commerce e Internet. Atualmente contamos com XX funcionários e nossos principais clientes são (coloque aqui o que sua empresa vende ou oferece). 

2- Fundada em (ano da fundação, por exemplo, 1998) pelo Senhor (nome do fundador), a principal missão da empresa (nome da empresa) é oferecer (coloque aqui o que sua empresa vende ou oferece). Nossos principais clientes são (nome dos clientes atuais) e atualmente contamos com XX funcionários. 

3- A missão da empresa (nome da empresa) é fornecer soluções para empresas de e-commerce e Internet. Nossos principais clientes são (coloque aqui o que sua empresa vende ou oferece). Fundada em (ano da fundação, por exemplo, 1998) pelo Senhor (nome do fundador), na cidade (nome da cidade), atualmente contamos com (quantidade de pessoas que trabalham na empresa) funcionários.
A empresa (nome da empresa) foi fundada no ano de (ano da fundação, por exemplo, 1998) na cidade (nome da cidade) pelo Senhor (nome do fundador) e sua principal missão é oferecer soluções para empresas de e-commerce e Internet. Atualmente contamos com XX funcionários e nossos principais clientes são (coloque aqui o que sua empresa vende ou oferece).
A empresa (nome da empresa) foi fundada no ano de (ano da fundação, por exemplo, 1998) na cidade (nome da cidade) pelo Senhor (nome do fundador) e sua principal missão é oferecer soluções para empresas de e-commerce e Internet. Atualmente contamos com XX funcionários e nossos principais clientes são (coloque aqui o que sua empresa vende ou oferece). 

2- Fundada em (ano da fundação, por exemplo, 1998) pelo Senhor (nome do fundador), a principal missão da empresa (nome da empresa) é oferecer (coloque aqui o que sua empresa vende ou oferece). Nossos principais clientes são (nome dos clientes atuais) e atualmente contamos com XX funcionários.   </P>

<div id="baixo"/>

</div>

</div>



<div class="rodape">


<a href="https://www.facebook.com/Alfatec-Autorizada-Electrolux-1737242946511224/" title="Facebook" target="_blank">
<img id= "facebook"  src="imagens/facebook-logo (2).png" alt="FaceBook" width="24" class="facebook" > 
</a>


</div>
```

Comment: Teu HTML não tem nada de bootstrap e nem de responsividade

Comment: poderia me ajudar ou me indicar algum lugar que eu possa aprender ?

Comment: Caio veja se isto ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/129074/3635 e depois leia a doc: http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: Muito obrigado !!